# Отправляется только 1 файл

Tags: python

Здраствуйте, у меня есть скрипт, который находит 4 файла в папке и отправляет их на почту, но почему то отправляется только 1 файл, возможно я что-то не знаю,

```
for file in (os.listdir(path)):
    filename = os.path.basename(file)
    ftype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(file)
    with open(rf"{path}/{file}", "rb") as f:
        file = MIMEBase(None,None)
        file.set_payload(f.read())
        encoders.encode_base64(file)
file.add_header('content-disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
msg.attach(file)
server.sendmail(addr_from, addr_to, msg.as_string())
```

Comment: Если вы вызываете attach ровно один раз, то вполне логично ожидать, что получится ровно один файл

Comment: все равно 1 файл, вызвал 4 раза

Comment: В цикле вызывайте))

Comment: так надо 4 раза с разными файлами, а не 4 раза с одним и тем же файлом

Comment: Мдам, туго без фигурных скобок конечно...

Answer (score 0):

```
file.add_header('content-disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
msg.attach(file)
```

У вас выпали из цикла

Comment: Добавить их внутри цикла?

Comment: я все равно не понял что выпало, извините

Comment: Строчки, эти команды выполняются только для последнего файла